# Horizontal only line thickness in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, line

Is there a way so line thickness only expands horizontally from the centreline? I am making a road condition map and found it may not be truly representable.

[image]

The red on the left overlaps the yellow (I do have a draw order of 'worse' first so it stands out more).

But would it be possible to have it so it is more of a rectangle of line width rather than a rounded rectangle? Or is the vertical extent of the line where it actually ends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the symbol for your roads to a Cartographic Line symbol rather than a Simple Line symbol. That will give you more control over how it's drawn. When you add a line layer to ArcMap, it defaults to a Simple Line symbol, which has the rounded ends you're seeing. With a Cartographic Line symbol, you can change the line end caps. You will probably want to use the "Butt" style:

[image]

You can find the symbol settings by double-clicking the line symbol in the Table of Contents and clicking Edit Symbol, then change the line type to cartographic line:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One quick question, is there a way to set this as default in Arc?

Comment: @AlanCarr I don't think so. You *can* change a few things about default symbology using the ArcMap Advanced Settings Utility, but line caps aren't one of them.